# Webpack loader configuration to load css and sass files for React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, css-loader, sass-loader

I have installed **react-h5-audio-player** in a React app made with create-react-app and it worked fine.

I did same to customized React project and I am being asked to configure webpack to load the css files.

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

I have attached screenshot of error log and code section where error happened[image]

The error (

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-h5-audio-player/lib/styles.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
```

) happened in the below css file, these css files are made by installed audio player (which is made with typescript)

```
.rhap_container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.rhap_container:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `css-loader` and `style-loader` to enable your webpack to bundle `CSS` files:

**Install the loaders:**

```
npm install css-loader style-loader --save-dev
npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev
```

**Set the rules in webpack config:**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

Check [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader), [style-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader) and [sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/)

Comment: Thanks it worked, however some css parts still missing in page, I mean the audio player UI is different, I hope I may need to add sass files too

Comment: How do I configure webpack for all kind of css related files ?

Comment: Thank you for the efforts, still something missing in the UI, unknown reasons

Comment: Appreciate your response, code is working now perfectly. forgot to install  style-loader, much love 4 u

Comment: Yeah, I use react with Django. Thanks for your info