# Getting an error - " You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file"

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, css-loader

I'm a beginner in React and stuck with some problem.Can't able to import the external css file in react app. And while importing I'm getting an error as " You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file". I have added a css loader and style loader in the webpack configbut still getting this error.

```
**Webpack.config.js**

var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')


var browserConfig = {
  entry: './src/browser/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'), // create a public folder
    // and inside this we'll create file named bundle.js which contain
    // the whole app contained in one file
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader'}, // whenever webpack found
      // any .js file then it will call babel-loader to convert JSX into
     // vanilla js
      {
       test:/\.css$/,
       use:['style-loader','css-loader']
    }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __isBrowser__: "true" // plugin help to know whether we are in 
      // browser rendered page or server rendered page.
    })
  ]
}

var serverConfig = {
 entry: './src/server/index.js',
 target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'server.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
  { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
  {
    test:/\.css$/,
    use:['style-loader','css-loader']
    }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __isBrowser__: "false"
    })
  ]
}

module.exports = [browserConfig, serverConfig]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "React-App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore public/",
    "dev-bundle": "webpack -w -d"
  },
     "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
       "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "serialize-javascript": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
 };
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './../styles/NavBar.css';


 export default function Home () {
     const myStyle = {
        "margin-left":"25%",
        "padding":"1px 16px",
        "height":"1000px"
   };
  return (
    <>
    <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   </ul>

    <div style={myStyle}>
  <h2>Fixed Full-height Side Nav</h2>

</div>
</>
  )
}
```

**NavBar.css**

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 25%;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
  }

  li a {
display: block;
color: #000;
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
  }

  li a.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
  }

  li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
  }
```

**Error**

```
C:\React-App\src\styles\NavBar.css:1
ul {
   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\React-App\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\React-App\src\shared\/Home.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62238145/2873538) help?

Comment: @Ajeet, Thanks for prompt response.I have tried all the workaround mentioned in the blog but still getting the same error.

Comment: Okay, one question: Why are you writing webpack config by yourself? Why didn't you use CRA to setup a react project which will come pre-configured with these loaders?

Comment: @AjeetShah because CRA comes with its own development server and build configuration. This build will generate static assets for client-side rendering; but it does not support server-side rendering and here I'm using SSR.

Answer (score 0):

Well your setup looks good , not sure about Home.js file. Haven't used it like that till now. May be its new way of writing.

Other vise try changing the file to Home.jsx and your webpack to

```
{ test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, use: 'babel-loader' }
```